# How to make navbar fixed in top of specific div instead of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two navbar one for full page and another for only div of page , i want to make my second div fixed on top after scrolling over that div .

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

My html for second navbar

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
  }

 .navbar a:hover {
   background: #ddd;
   color: black;
    }
```

My css is here. I want second navbar top of the page only when the div is scroll down.I am poor at js.

Comment: Is this Bootstrap 3? Can you also add a snippet of your current code? So that we have something to test on

Comment: You are using Bootstrap 3, correct?

Comment: `position: fixed`?

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding how to ask good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.element-you-want-to-stick {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

from [this](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/xGggLa)